# How can i get the second sample is from the set exclude the first sample in R?

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I would like to have the first sample from A, and another one from A exclude the first sample.

How could do it?

```
A <- matrix(sample(1:40,160,replace=TRUE),nrow=40,ncol=4)

s1 <- sample(A,4,replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you want to sample just individual values? (that is what you currently do). If so, why to use matrix? Or do you want to sample one row of the matrix?

Comment: Agree with Zbynek, it's not clear if you want a row or a random set of values.

Comment: How to handle duplicate numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in this way :

```
s <- sample(A, 4*2, replace = FALSE)
s1 <- s[1:4]
s2 <- s[5:8]
```

Comment: `setdiff` will remove all duplicate values.